# Error with calling a private constructor on macos

Tags: macos, boost, compiler-errors, g++, clang++

I am trying to port some C++ code that encodes the given data into base64 to macos. This is the a code sample from the same source which compiles and executes on godbolt but not on my mac:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <boost/archive/iterators/base64_from_binary.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/transform_width.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/insert_linebreaks.hpp>

using namespace boost::archive::iterators;

struct Encode
{
    /// Sets the contents of an std::string to be used
    /// as the input for the encoding operation.
    /// \param a_Data The string to encode.
    Encode(const std::string& a_Data);

    /// Evaluates the expression and performs the base64 encoding.
    /// \returns Base64 encoded string.
    operator std::string() const;
private:
    std::string Evaluate() const;

    const char * m_Data;
    size_t m_Size;
    bool m_LineBreaks;
};

Encode::Encode(const std::string& a_Data)
    : m_Data(a_Data.c_str())
    , m_Size(a_Data.size())
    , m_LineBreaks(false)
{
}

std::string Encode::Evaluate() const
{
    typedef base64_from_binary<
            transform_width<std::string::const_iterator,6,8>
        > iterator;

    typedef insert_linebreaks<iterator, 72> linebreak_iterator;

    std::string base64;
    if (m_LineBreaks) {
        base64.assign(
            linebreak_iterator(m_Data),
            linebreak_iterator(m_Data + m_Size));
    }
    else {
        base64.assign(
            iterator(m_Data),
            iterator(m_Data + m_Size));
    }

    return base64;
}
Encode::operator std::string() const
{
    return Evaluate();
}

int main()
{
    const std::string str64 = Encode("Hello World");    
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling using g++:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

However, there is the following error on line `iterator(m_Data),`:

```
boost/archive/iterators/transform_width.hpp:112:17: error: calling a private constructor of class 'std::__1::__wrap_iter<const char *>'
        super_t(Base(static_cast< T >(start))),
                ^
<build_path>/boost/archive/iterators/base64_from_binary.hpp:91:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::archive::iterators::transform_width<std::__1::__wrap_iter<const char *>, 6, 8,
      char>::transform_width<const char *>' requested here
            Base(static_cast< T >(start)),
            ^
<src_path>/utilsBase64.cc:105:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::archive::iterators::base64_from_binary<boost::archive::iterators::transform_width<std::__1::__wrap_iter<const char *>, 6, 8, char>, char>::base64_from_binary<const
      char *>' requested here
            iterator(m_Data),
            ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:1420:31: note: declared private here
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY __wrap_iter(iterator_type __x) _NOEXCEPT_DEBUG : __i(__x) {}
                              ^
```

I have attempted to use clang++ and tried setting `-stdlib=libc++` or `stdlib=libstdc++` with a similar result. All examples of using the base64_from_binary shown in the code are similar to the given code sample.

One additional detail about m_Data, it is a member variable declared as: `const char * m_Data;`

Could someone please explain how this can be resolved?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Note it should contain all necessary `#include` directives.

Comment: This should show the full code and the error too: https://godbolt.org/z/unFtHf

Comment: A [mcve] shoild be in the question itself, not a link and not in comments. Godbolt is utterly unusable on mobile.

Comment: Updated the original question with a complete example. Also, some more observations. On godbolt, setting the compiler flags to have `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` seems to cause the same error. But not setting the flags or setting them to `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++` fixes it. Following the same on my mac yields different results, i.e. I always get the same error.

Comment: What is your error message when compiling with -stdlib=libstdc++?

Comment: It is the same as the one posted in the question.

Comment: @n.m. I apologize. I don't get the same error with libstdc++. But, I cannot really use the GNU std library that comes with mac os High Sierra since it is not updated and cannot use it something like `#include <thread>` in the code. I will have to use the libc++. Unless my understanding of this is totally inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the code to the following helped fix the issue:

```
std::string Encode::Evaluate() const
{
    typedef base64_from_binary<
            transform_width<std::string::const_iterator,6,8>
        > iterator;

    typedef insert_linebreaks<iterator, 72> linebreak_iterator;

    std::string data(m_Data, m_Size);
    std::string base64;
    if (m_LineBreaks) {
        base64.assign(
            linebreak_iterator(data.begin()),
            linebreak_iterator(data.end()));
    }
    else {
        base64.assign(
            iterator(data.begin()),
            iterator(data.end()));
    }

    return base64;
}
```